# How to create a Calculated Field in dimple.js

Tags: dimple.js

How do i add a calculated field (a field which does calculation of two or more data fields) in dimple.js?

eg. I have two fields
1. "Sales Value"
2. "Sales Volume"

Now i have to calculate a field ASP = Sales Value /Sales Volume.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid dimple doesn't have a built in way to handle this.  I assume dimple is aggregating the data for you - hence the difficulty.  But here you have no option but to pre-aggregate to the level of a data point and add the calculated field yourself. For example if your data had Brand, SKU and Channel but your chart was at the Brand, Channel level you would need to pre-process the data like this:

```
// var chartData is going to be the aggregated level you use for your chart.
// var added is a dictionary of aggregated data returning a row index 
// for each Brand/Channel combination.
var chartData = [],
    added = {};

// Aggregate to the Brand/Channel level
data.forEach(function (d) {
    var key = d["Brand"] + "|" + d["Channel"],
        i = added[key];

    // Check the output index
    if (i !== undefined) {
        // Brand/Channel have been added already so add the measures
        chartData[i]["Sales Value"] += parseFloat(d["Sales Value"]);
        chartData[i]["Sales Volume"] += parseFloat(d["Sales Volume"]);
    } else {
        // Get the index for the row we are about to add
        added[key] = chartData.length;
        // Insert a new output row for the Brand/Channel
        chartData.push({
            "Brand": d["Brand"],
            "Channel": d["Channel"],
            "Sales Value": parseFloat(d["Sales Value"]) || 0,
            "Sales Volume": parseFloat(d["Sales Volume"]) || 0
        });
    }
});

// Calculate ASP
chartData.forEach(function (d) {
    d["ASP"] = d["Sales Value"] / d["Sales Volume"];
});

// Draw the chart using chartData instead of data
...
```